# Understanding a let-expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and currently studying it for an exam. I have been learning it from learnyouahaskell. I don't understand the following let-expression in the group function.

```
splitWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])    
splitWhen p xs = (takeWhile (not . p) xs, dropWhile (not . p) xs)

group :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = let (group1, rest) = splitWhen (/=x) xs
                   in (x:group1) : group rest
```

I know what splitWhen does: `splitWhen even [1,2,3] => ([1],[2,3])`

I know that the function group produce the follow:

```
group [1,1,2,1,3,3,3] => [[1,1],[2],[1],[3,3,3]]
```

I don't understand how it works. Can someone please explain it to me?
Thank you.

Comment: What part about it specifically are you asking about? `(/=x)`?

Comment: the entire let (group1, rest) = splitWhen (/=x) xs
                   in (x:group1) : group rest

Comment: You'll need to look up deconstruction to figure out the part right after `let`, and recursion and the cons constructor for the part after `in`. Explaining the entirety of those lines is overly broad though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` expressions are syntactic sugar for the immediate application of an anonymous function. That is,

```
let (group1, rest) = splitWhen (/=x) xs
    in (x:group1) : group rest
```

is equivalent to

```
(\(group1, rest) -> (x:group1) : group rest) (splitWhen (/=x) xs)
```

Put another way, `let` inverts the positions of the body of the function and the argument to the function. Compare

```
let name =  value in body
(  \name -> body  )  value
```

Comment: So i apply `splitWhen` first and this generates me a tuple of lists `([a],[a])`. To this i apply the lambda function, which adds the x to the first list of the tuple and it iterate to the second. Did i get it?

Comment: Basically. Keep in mind, though, that Haskell is lazy, so `splitWhen` will only be called once someone starts using the return value of `group`. Better to say that `group1` and `rest` are bound to the tuple elements returned by `splitWhen` and used in the body of the `let` expression to produce the desired list.

Comment: Yes, Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
let (group1, rest) = splitWhen (/=x) xs
```

This calls `splitWhen (/=x) xs` and uses pattern matching on the returned tuple to assign it to `(group1, rest)`. Then these values can be used in

```
in (x:group1) : group rest
```

To calculate the final result of the function.

You can implement this as a `where` clause and get the same behavior:

```
group (x:xs) = (x:group1) : group rest
    where (group1, rest) = splitWhen (/=x) xs
```